# Fill the difference C++ ==

Tags: c++, operators, equality

we have to expressions
`if ((option & SERVER_OPTIONS::VALUE) == SERVER_OPTIONS::VALUE)
...`

```
if ( option & SERVER_OPTIONS::VALUE == SERVER_OPTIONS::VALUE )...
```

Why for same values of `option` there is different result?

Comment: There are some questions that are simply baffling. Why for the same values of 1, 2 and 3 does `1 + 2 * 3` have a different result than `(1 + 2) * 3`?

Comment: -1 for this question. You will finde what your are looking for at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fatf1t6a%28v=VS.100%29.aspx?lc=1033

Comment: @RaphaelB. Wait, isn't that list for JScript (even though it probably mostly applies to C++, too)? The one for C++ is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/126fe14k(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 13):

[C++ operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) states that `==`and `!=` are evaluated **before** `&`. So your second statement gets evaluated as if it were this:

```
if (option & (SERVER_OPTIONS::VALUE == SERVER_OPTIONS::VALUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

In this statement

`if ((option & SERVER_OPTIONS::VALUE) == SERVER_OPTIONS::VALUE)`

this `option & SERVER_OPTIONS::VALUE` part is evaluated first as of () higher precedence.
And in the latter case `SERVER_OPTIONS::VALUE == SERVER_OPTIONS::VALUE` is evaluated first. Order of execution determines result of an expression.